Slightly wrong color in MP4 videos written by PyAV
I am writing MP4 video files with the following PyAV-based code (getting input frames represented as numpy arrays - the sort produced by imageio.imread - as input):
class MP4:
    def __init__(self, fname, width, height, fps):
        self.output = av.open(fname, 'w', format='mp4')
        self.stream = self.output.add_stream('h264', str(fps))
        self.stream.width = width
        self.stream.height = height
        # these 2 lines can be removed and the problem still reproduces:
        self.stream.pix_fmt = 'yuv420p'
        self.stream.options = {'crf': '17'}
    def write_frame(self, pixels):
        frame = av.VideoFrame.from_ndarray(pixels, format='rgb24')
        packet = self.stream.encode(frame)
        self.output.mux(packet)
    def close(self):
        packet = self.stream.encode(None)
        self.output.mux(packet)
        self.output.close()

The colors in the output MP4 video are slightly different (apparently darker) than the colors in the input images:
Screen grab of an image viewer showing an input frame:

Screen grab of VLC playing the output MP4 video:

How can this problem be fixed? I variously fiddled with the frame.colorspace attribute, stream options and VideoFrame.reformat but it changed nothing; of course I could have been fiddling incorrectly.
As you can see, the input has simple flat color regions, so I doubt it's any sort of compression artifact, eg YUV420 dropping some of the chroma info or other such.

You only set crf but you need other settings like a colorspace option or maybe even a video filter vf option to adjust output colours. See if this Answer is useful and then try colorspace options as shown at bottom of this article. You can use same colour settings with a Video Filter to force a specific output pixel colours. One of those will match your input.

PS: You need to ask this at SuperUser. Re-write your question to work (testable) in command line FFmpeg, then you'll get faster help there.

Thank you very much! With your help I've discovered that on the command line, ffmpeg works just as badly with the default options, but it produces the correct colors given -colorspace bt709.
So now I'm still trying to figure out how to achieve the equivalent effect using PyAV's APIs (which I guess is a question to SO more than SuperUser after all...)

Adding frame = frame.reformat(format='yuv420p', dst_colorspace=av.video.reformatter.Colorspace.ITU709) before the call to encode fixes the problem. I don't know why both the format and the dst_colorspace arguments are needed for this to work, empirically they are.

Interesting that it had to be applied to the input (instead of the output side). Also +1 for solving your own question with a useful answer.

Try setting the .options Object as:
self.stream.options = {'crf': '17' , 'colorspace': 'bt709' , 'color_primaries': 'bt709'}


Same wrong output color, and I also tried setting {stream.codec_context,frame}.{colorspace,color_range,color_tsc,color_primaries} - I actually expected setting frame's attributes to work since the ffmpeg -colorspace option, according to ffmpeg's printouts, modifies the input PNGs' colorspace, not the output sequence's, which is confirmed by checking these attributes by opening the good & bad ffmpeg output files using PyAV & printing the values - both good & bad file have the same attributes and it's not bt709. But setting the input frame's colorspace does nothing, too...
